# how can you say 'the person I'm talking with' with one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, instead of saying 'you have to listen to the person you are talking with',  I want to say: 'You have to listen to your ___________'

Comment: It's ugly, but how about *conversational partner*?

Answer (score 13):

The word is ***interlocutor***. "You have to hear/listen to your ***interlocutor***."

But it can refer to anyone taking part in a conversation.

Comment: Is it also correct if the conversation is in written form?

Comment: That would be _correspondent_

Answer (score 5):

## "collocutor," meaning "The person with/to whom one is speaking."

collocutor
noun  col·loc·u·tor  \kəˈläkyətə(r), kōˈ- ˈkäləˌkyütə(r)\
Definition of collocutor

:  a person to or with whom one speaks

© 2015 Merriam-Webster, Incorporated