# Word for the person to which a question is addressed

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If you ask a question, you'd be the asker and the other party would be the ____.

I thought of "askee", but this is not a word.

Comment: Askee is absolutely a word, its just one you might not want to use in some contexts. The dictionary is not the ultimate arbiter of wordhood.

Comment: Not quite the same, but have a look at [how can you say 'the person I'm talking with' with one word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296995/how-can-you-say-the-person-im-talking-with-with-one-word).

Comment: Also consider *addressee* for the person to whom the question was addressed. It's possibly more closely related to envelope addresses, but it sounds like it fits.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73616/questionee-inquiree-interrogatee

Comment: @Elian The post you indicated in comments matches this question better than the one placed by the closure notice - this question allows the possibility that the person addressed doesn't answer.

Comment: @Elian You are saying that 'person asked' is identical to 'person answering'. I suggest you re-open this for incorrectly closing, or adjust the cited duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *addressee* is the word. But it certainly depends on the situation.  *An answerer, a respondent* would do as well.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would guess that the person would be a "listener" if he wasn't answering the question; then he would be the "answerer". So it depends on context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the appropriate choice is **audience** as in the following examples:

> Who is **audience** of the question? (Depends on the question. For the question, 'What is a 7th grade student's favorite color?', the audience is 7th grade students.)

and

> feel that the **intended audience** of The Question Book is young, professional and quite possibly male. Almost twenty pages of the book's 160 ...